# How to represent Smullyan's "Mockingbird" puzzles in (Homotopy) Type Theory?

Tags: constructive-mathematics, type-theory, combinatory-logic, homotopy-type-theory

(If you're unfamiliar with the puzzles from To Mock a Mockingbird, [three pages](http://books.google.com/books?id=NyF1kvJhZbAC&lpg=PA1&pg=PT121#v=onepage&q&f=false) tell you everything you should need.)

## Is it possible to solve the riddles in To Mock a Mockingbird in a "propositions as types" style?

As an example, let's take the second problem:

> A bird x is called *egocentric* (sometimes *narcissistic*) if it is fond of itself—that is, if x's response to x is x. In symbols, x is egocentric if xx = x.
>   The problem is to prove that under the given conditions $\text{C}_1$ and $\text{C}_2$ of the last problem, at least one bird is egocentric.

In something like Higher-Order Logic, I would define egocentricity like

```
definition egocentric :: "Bird => Bool" where
  "egocentric A == (call A A = A)"
```

(assuming `call :: Bird => Bird => Bird`)

A naive attempt at encoding egocentricity as a type would be
$$
\text{egocentric} : \textbf{Bird} \rightarrow \operatorname{call}(A,A)=A
$$

However, an obvious problem is that $A$ isn't bound in the [identity type](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/identity+type)
$$
\operatorname{call}(A,A)=A
$$
(which, in [HoTT](http://homotopytypetheory.org) is "judgmentally equal" to the type $\textbf{Id}_{\textbf{Bird}}(\operatorname{call}(A,A), A)$)
So, we need a *dependent* function definition, right?
$$
\text{egocentric} : \Pi A:\textbf{Bird}. call(A, A) =_\textbf{Bird} A
$$

But... that doesn't *look* like the type-theory equivalent of an unary predicate; it looks like the claim "Every bird's response to its own name is its name"!

### If it's helpful to instead ask a very specific question:

Given the "composition" and "mockingbird" conditions (q.v. [the book's *first* exercise](http://books.google.com/books?id=NyF1kvJhZbAC&lpg=PA1&pg=PT123#v=onepage&q&f=false)), how would you construct a term of the following type? $$\Pi A:\textbf{Bird}. \Sigma x:\textbf{Bird}. \operatorname{call}(A, x) = x$$
(Sorta implicit: how would you encode the "composition" and "mockingbird" givens?)

Comment: What do you mean by "unary predicate"?  The definition in type theory is the same as your definition in "higher-order logic", except that you replace "Bool" with "Type" (because `\forall x. call A x = A` is translated to $\prod_x \text{call}\ A\ x = A$).

Comment: By "unary predicate" I mean a function of one argument with return type `Bool`. And _that's_ really just a formalization of the intuitive concept "an attribute that a single object can have". So, using the same kind of language, an attribute that a _pair_ of objects can have would be a "binary predicate".

Comment: Do you have a terminating procedure for enumerating all birds and a terminating procedure for deciding when two birds are the same?  If not, how can you hope to decide whether or not a bird is egocentric?

Comment: In general attributes are not functions to `Bool`; that only talks about decidable/computable attributes.  You want a function to `Prop` to talk about arbitrary attributes.

Comment: @Jason, you're bringing up valid, practical points, but I don't _think_ the type `Prop` is relevant in Homotopy Type Theory (which is where I'm learning Type Theory). There's a short explanatory paragraph [here](https://github.com/HoTT/book/blob/master/coq_introduction/Reading_HoTT_in_Coq.v#L1024-1028). When I wrote the question, I didn't realize how much of the language & theory was HoTT-specific. I'll update the title to reflect that.

Comment: In that case, you want `hProp` if the type of birds is a set, and `Type` if it has higher path structure.

Answer (score 2):

Let's take things slowly. First things first: $\mathsf{egocentric}$ is a predicate, so it is a $\mathsf{Type}$-valued function of some kind. In this case, it is a function $\mathsf{Bird} \to \mathsf{Type}$. It is defined as follows:
$$\mathsf{egocentric} \equiv \lambda A : \mathsf{Bird} . \mathsf{call}(A, A) =_{\mathsf{Bird}} A$$
Thus:
$$\mathop{\mathsf{egocentric}} A \equiv \mathsf{call}(A, A) =_{\mathsf{Bird}} A$$

That said, I question your motives. There is no benefit in thinking about the problem in this way. It is more useful to work directly with the (typed) $\lambda$-calculus built into type theory than to build try an internal model of it.